# Finding string around pattern of Strings

Tags: regex, python-3.x, nlp, spacy

Regular expression(May be) to find the word/string surrounded by other words.

===========================================================================
For example I have below sentences

1.I’m setting up a new server, The key is ABC and want to support UTF-8 fully in my web application. Where do I need to set the encoding/charsets?”

2.XYZ is the key for the new server I am setting and it is located at address 111 abc

3.key as of the date  is WWW for the new server I am setting at 111, ABC London

4.The key for server is LMN and it is being setup at location 111, abc London.

key will be finite and will only have around 10 values. The value for key itself can be any form though. I have used ACB, XYZ, WWW, LMN as example above

I should be able to identify that Key exists in the sentence and extract value(ACB, XYZ, WWW, LMN)  from all the above examples.

I have basically tried finding using if then else which is very cumbersome and dont have very good code to show yet. But will update when I can

I have basically tried finding using if then else which is very cumbersome and dont have very good code to show yet. But will update when I can

I should be able to identify that Key exists in the sentence and extract value(ACB, XYZ, WWW, LMN)  from all the above examples.

Another option could be to use Spacy with dependency parsing

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Still looking for solution...appreciate any pointers

Answer (score 0):

This expression is likely to return the desired output, not sure though:

```
^(?=.*\b(ABC|XYZ|WWW|LMN)\b).*$
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gyT6Oo/1/)

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r"^(?=.*\b(ABC|XYZ|WWW|LMN)\b).*$"

test_str = """
1.I’m setting up a new server, The key is ABC and want to support UTF-8 fully in my web application. Where do I need to set the encoding/charsets?”

2.XYZ is the key for the new server I am setting and it is located at address 111 abc

3.Key as of the date is WWW for the new server I am setting at 111, ABC London

4.The key for server is LMN and it is being setup at location 111, abc London.
"""

print(re.findall(regex, test_str,re.M))
```

#### Output

```
['ABC', 'XYZ', 'ABC', 'LMN']
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/A0oFzH/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/A0oFzH/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

Comment: ABC|XYZ|WWW|LMN is just example I used, it can be in any form. The key is to find the presence of key(no pun intended :) ) and extract value associated with key

Comment: The regular expression just tries to find the value of key, I need to first find the presence of keyword 'key' and then extract value associated with it . Value can be any alhanumeric value and special characters. Thanks for your suggestion though. Keyeword key can have upto 10 values in itself and is limited to a list